# Components are all returning empty values

Tags: rules

I am trying to run a rules component as the child to a parent rule and I'm only getting an empty value returned to me.

I create the component, the field I will be returning is generated within the component, and then I pass it along (theoretically) by creating a provided variable (we'll call this variable X) in the settings section with the same machine name.

When we get back to my parent rule, it says that it is adding X, however X is empty.

Am I not passing variables correctly from the child component to the parent rule? How is this supposed to be done? Is there another step I need to do besides making the value a provided variable?

Comment: are you sure the component is generating the correct value?  try adding a show message action to the component to check if the component is functioning properly

Comment: I was able to get around this by creating a variable that was parameter + provided and just setting the value inside the child component. Does not appear to be working as intended.